# Doing a search in Android Studio causes LogCat to stop working?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm on a mac using Android Studio 0.5.2

I am running a project and logging via LogCat.  It prints normally.  Then, I do a file search (cmd + shft + f in file directory) and LogCat no longer prints anything to the console.  This has happened a few times.  If I completely close the emulator and Android Studio, then restart, it works fine again.  This takes a long time and is extremely annoying.  I'm trying to familiarize myself with Android, so I do a lot of file searches and this is unacceptable.  To be clear, LogCat is showing, but none of my Logs are printing to it.

Is there a way to run a reset of LogCat within Android Studio that can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Android Studio 0.5.8 currently so can't reproduce the issue as you said, But let me give you a way so that you don't need to restart Studio.

**Prerequisite**

You have to set your environmental variable to access adb commands anywhere through terminal

Reference link :https://sites.google.com/site/richgossweiler/home/android-development-notes/installing-the-android-sdk-on-windows

Try "adb devices" command somewhere to just make sure things are working fine.

Restart Android Studio if it is running .

you will see a Terminal tab inside Android Studio's bottom tab bar panel. open and run the following commands to restart the android debug bridge interface .

```
adb kill-server

adb start-server
```

let me know if it works for you.

enjoy the code with Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have to get some sleep at the moment, but I'll try this tomorrow.  I didn't even know I could interact with the console, so +1 regardless.  I'll accept if this solves it for me!

Comment: @Logan sure, will be happy if it will solve the issue you have.